# SQL WHERE clause matching on the same field twice (or more). What is the right JOIN statement to be used?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, where-clause

I have a DB with two tables:

- employees table: fields = {ID, name}
- turnShift table: fields = {ID, date, ID_employee1, ID_employee2}

Here is an example of this DB.

[image]

Using MYSQL, I'd like to execute a SELECT query able to show the names of both employees involved in each turn shift.

The following picture shows the desired query results using the previous db example:

[image]

Comment: This looks like it might be homework so I'll only give a hint. You can join the employee table twice, just give each table a different alias. e.g. `join employee as employee1 on shift.id_employee1=employee1.id`

Comment: @mpen You could always join twice but that will result in a bigger join table. I wonder if there's a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I was thinking about JOIN, but don't know which is the right one to be used in this context.

Comment: Use `join` (aka inner join) if the records in both tables always exist or you don't want nulls. Use `left join` if the records in the secondary table might not exist but you still want a result back (filled with nulls). Forget about the other kinds of joins, they're almost never what you want.

Comment: @JanezKuhar The resulting table will be exactly the size OP wants. The other way to do it is with 2 queries and stitch the result together in your programming language of choice, but I think that'd be less efficient if there's exactly 2 employees per shift.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```
SELECT
  t.ID AS turnShiftID,
  t.date AS turnShiftDate,
  e1.name AS employee1Name,
  e2.name AS employee2Name
FROM
  turnShift t
  INNER JOIN employees e1 ON t.ID_employee1 = e1.ID
  INNER JOIN employees e2 ON t.ID_employee2 = e2.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd query the `turn_shift` table and join on the `employee` table twice, once for each column of IDs you want to convert to names:

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.date, e1.name AS name_employee1, e2.name AS name_employee2
FROM   turn_shift t
JOIN   employee e1 ON t.id_employee1 = e1.id
JOIN   employee e2 ON t_id_employee2 = e2.id
```